# Getting Uploadify to work with Codeigniter?

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, uploadify

Has anyone been able to get [uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) to work with codeigniter?

Everything I try it will not upload.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you checked the links below?

[Uploadify forum post](http://uploadify.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=47&p=210&hilit=codeigniter#p210)
[Codeigniter forum post](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/109751/)