# Using Uploadify with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload, upload, uploadify

I'm having trouble implementing the uploadify in CodeIgniter. The when i click to upload the selected file, the process bar runs successfully, however the file is not uploaded. 
I think the script never reads the upload.php file located in the upload folder.

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/jquery.uploadify.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#fileUpload").fileUpload({
        'uploader': '<?php echo base_url(); ?>uploadify/uploader.swf',
        'cancelImg': '<?php echo base_url(); ?>uploadify/cancel.png',
        'script': '<?php echo base_url(); ?>uploadify/upload.php',
        'folder': 'upload/files',
        'multi': false,
        'displayData': 'speed', 
    }); 
});

</script>
```

Please note the above folder path. The files structure is following:

```
upload/application     //codeigniter application folder
upload/system         //codeigniter system folder
upload/uploadify     //uploadify folder
upload/files        //where i want to move uploaded files.
```

I have tried this also:

```
'folder': '<?php echo base_url(); ?>/files',
```

Here is my upload.php file(upload/uploadify/upload.php" content

```
<?php

if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    $tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
    $targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $_GET['folder'] . '/';
    $targetFile =  str_replace('//','/',$targetPath) . $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];

    move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
}

echo '1';

?>
```

My second question is that is it possible that instead of using the above upload.php file, i can use the function in the controller? If yes, how that can be done?

Please help me to fix this problem.

Comment: I also try use the codeigniter controller to solve this, but becomes a nightmare, you can find some exemples in this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465816/getting-uploadify-to-work-with-codeigniter) of stackoverflow to help you. I prefer stay in the root of website and keep uploadify just the way that was build.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. Check that your temporary upload directory is writable by Apache (the usual problem)
2. If you don't think upload.php is being called then stick an echo or log-to-file statement in it to check